# JanusGraph Pre-Packaged Distribution: Cassandra forking exceeded timeout

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, janusgraph

I am installing JanusGraph on my computer (following [the official guide](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/#using-the-pre-packaged-distribution)) such that the data is stored on my computer which will also act like the client. I figured it would be best to use the Pre-Packaged Distribution (`janusgraph-full-0.6.1.zip` on [the official JanusGraph repository](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.6.1)) which is pre-configured with a sample Cassandra/Elastic Search configuration.

Once I have unzipped the file, if I want to launch JanusGraph (through `bin/janusgraph.sh start`), I obtain the following results:

```
> bin/janusgraph.sh start
Forking Cassandra...
Running `nodetool statusbinary`................... timeout exceeded (60 seconds)
See /<PATH_TO_JANUSGRAPH>/janusgraph-full-0.6.1/bin/../logs/cassandra.log for Cassandra log output.
```

While it says to see `/<PATH_TO_JANUSGRAPH>/janusgraph-full-0.6.1/bin/../logs/cassandra.log` for logs, there is no such file.

My thoughts were that this Distribution was able to work as a standalone, without any prior installation of Cassandra nor Elastic Search. Is it a misunderstanding on my part? If not, where does the timeout comes and how to fix it?

Thanks to everyone who will read it and take the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Downgrade from whatever Java version you're using to Java 8

After some slight digging in [the `janusgraph.sh` code](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/static/bin/janusgraph.sh) I found the verbose option (which is exactly the same as everywhere, might be a good idea for next time):

```
>bin/janusgraph.sh -v start
Forking Cassandra...
Running `nodetool statusbinary`.[0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/home/pelegrin/Documents/Progs/JanusGraph/janusgraph-full-0.6.1/bin/../cassandra/bin/../logs/gc.log instead.
intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

When researching `intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]` on Google, one of the first results is [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46936170/cassandra-and-java-9-threadprioritypolicy-42-is-outside-the-allowed-range) on Cassandra and Java 9, where it is said that downgrading the Java version to Java 8 is the simplest way to solve this error.

Indeed, after installing Java 8 and switching to this version ([follow the answer here if needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133216/downgrading-java-11-to-java-8)) everything worked as expected!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  Which version of Cassandra is being run there?  Cassandra 4 _will_ run on Java 11.

Comment: I'll try and dive into the folders to find this, but I doubt it will be v4 as the Tested Compatibility section (https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.6.1) indicates Apache Cassandra compatibilities with v3.0.14 and v3.11.10.

Comment: After further investigation, it seems that it indeed is Cassandra v3.11.10 that is being installed with the Pre-Packaged Distribution.